# Does an explicit formula exist for this number theoretic function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $n,m,k$ be natural numbers such that $\gcd(n,k)=1$ and $k^m \equiv 1 \mod n$. Next define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set { $0,1,\dots, n-1$ } via
$$ a\sim b \iff a\equiv bk^r \mod n \quad \text{for some integer $r$} $$
Let $r_a$ denote the cardinality of the equivalence class of $a$ under this equivalence relation. Let $S(a,b,c)$ count the number of ways of writing $c$ as the sum of an element from the equivalence class of $a$ and an element from the equivalence class of $b$. I.e,
$$ S(a,b,c) =  |\text{\{ $(r,s): 0\leq r<r_a, 0\leq s<r_b: ak^r+bk^s\equiv c\mod n$ \}} |  $$
Does there exist an explicit formula for $S(a,b,c)$ in terms of $r_a,r_b$ and $r_c$? If not how about in the special case of $S(a,b,a+bk^t)$ for some $0\leq t<r_b$? I've been studying the characters of the metacyclic groups and when I went to try to compute the product of two arbitary characters this questions naturally arose. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I meant the cardinality of the equivalence class, thanks.